# Magento 2 - Move homepage cms content after a custom div

Tags: magento2, layout, xml

I have a custom phtml file that I've included on the homepage, this has several divs that call in static blocks. Here is a simplified version:

```
<div class="my-div-1">
    <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('my_block_1')->toHtml();?>       
</div>

<div class="my-div-2">
    <?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('my_block_1')->toHtml();?>       
</div>
```

And here is how I've called it in on the homepage:

```
<referenceContainer name="main">
  <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="homepage_content" template="Magento_Cms::homepage-content.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

In my `cms_index_index.xml` I want to move the cms content block between `.my-div-1` and `.my-div-2` but I'm struggling to get the right reference. I currently have it wrapped in a div as follows:

```
<referenceContainer name='content'>
  <container name='homepage-section' as='homepage-section' htmlTag='div' htmlClass='homepage-section cms' />
</referenceContainer>
<move element='cms_page' destination='homepage-section'/>
```

Can someone help me with moving this between my 2 divs please, or can it not be done?

Comment: You could try splitting your custom phtml into to e.g. hometop.phtml and homebottom.phtml. Then adding one block to the top of content and one to the bottom of content?

Comment: Of course, why didn't I think of that! Cheers, I'll give it a go now!

Comment: After a bit more cursing I've done it. Thanks again for your help. If you want to put it as an answer I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split your custom phtml into 2 e.g. hometop.phtml and homebottom.phtml.

Then add one block to the top of content and one to the bottom of content.